# Do we have the following "devissage commutative diagram" in K-theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $X$ be a non-reduced Noetherian scheme. We define $K^0(X)$ to be the Grothendieck group of the derived category $Perf(X)$ and $K_0(X)$ to be the  Grothendieck group of the derived category $D^b_{coh}(X)$. Then we have a natural Cartan homomorphism
$$
K^0(X)\to K_0(X).
$$
given by inclusion of the derived categories $Perf(X)\subset D^b_{coh}(X)$.

Next we consider the associated reduced scheme $X_{red}$ with $f: X_{red}\to X$ and we have $K^0(X_{red})$ and $K_0(X_{red})$ also. 
Moreover there are natural maps
$$
f^*:K^0(X)\to K^0(X_{red})
$$
and
$$
f_*:K_0(X_{red})\to K_0(X).
$$

By the devissage theorem in K-theory, $f_*:K_0(X_{red})\to K_0(X)$ is an isomorphism but this is not true for $f^*$.

My question is: do we have the following commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
K^0(X)&{\rightarrow}&K_0(X)\\
\downarrow\scriptstyle{f^*}&&\uparrow\scriptstyle{\cong}\\
K^0(X_{red})&{\rightarrow}&K_0(X_{red})?
\end{array}$$

Comment: That square is not commutative.  Just consider the images of the element $1$ in $K^0(X)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you Jason! Actually this question is inspired by your answer to my previous MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203145/is-k0x-to-k-0x-monomorphic-for-a-noetherian-scheme-x, where you mentioned that the composition $Pic(X)\hookrightarrow K^0(X)\to K_0(X)$  factors through the pull back $Pic(X)\to Pic(X_{red})$. I think the latter goes to $K^0(X_{red})$ and then to $K_0(X_{red})$. That's why I thought there is a commutative diagram in K-theory. Could you explain a little bit more why the map from the Picard group factors through $Pic(X_{red})$?

Comment: The map from $K_0(X_{\text{red}})$ to $K_0(X)$ that completes that commutative diagram is not the pushforward map.  It is a $K^0(X)$-module homomorphism that sends the class $[\mathcal{O}_{X_{\text{red}}}]$ to $[\mathcal{O}_X]$.

Comment: @JasonStarr You mean the isomorphism $K_0(X)\overset{\cong}{\to}K_0(X_{red})$ is given by the pull back $f^*$, isn't it?

Comment: "You mean ..."  No, that is not what I am saying.  Here is another way of saying it: since the pushforward map $K_0(f)$ is an isomorphism of $K^0(X)$-modules, and since the action of $K^0(X)$ on $K_0(X_{\text{red}})$ is induced by the ring homomorphism $K^0(f):K^0(X)\to K^0(X_{\text{red}})$, it follows that the ideal $\text{Ker}(K^0(f))$ annihilates $K_0(X)$.  In particular, if this ideal is nonzero (which can easily be arranged), then the induced homomorphism $K^0(X)\to K_0(X)$ is not injective.

Comment: @JasonStarr I got your last reasoning that $K^0(X)\to K_0(X)$ is not injective. Nevertheless I'm also interested in your comment "The map from $K_0(X_{red})$ to $K_0(X)$ that completes that commutative diagram is not the pushforward map. It is a $K^0(X)$-module homomorphism that sends the class $[\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}]$ to $[\mathcal{O}_X]$". Is this map well-defined and an isomorphism?

Comment: You may be right.  At any rate, the point of my answer to your original question is that $\text{Ker}(K^0(f))$ annihilates $K_0(X)$.  However, now I am not certain whether or not there is a homomorphism from $K_0(X_{\text{red}})$ to $K_0(X)$ making the diagram commute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23378/discussion-between-zhaoting-wei-and-jason-starr).